# close window after download file generates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have `javascript` code for generate pdf file.
For that i have `url` which generates pdf file. I dont want user to see that url thats why i am using iframe in hidden to load that url and generate download popup.
However its working for me, but now what i want to do is to open that iframe content in new tab, wait till download popup generate and then close that window.

See my javascript,

```
var iframe;
var url="test.com?file=download";
iframe="<iframe src='"+url+"' style='visibility:hidden' >";

var html="<html>";
        html+="<head>";
        html+="</head>";
        html+="<body>";
        html+= iframe;
        html+="</body>";
        html+="</html>";
        var printWin = window.open('','_blank','left=0,top=0,fullscreen,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');
        printWin.document.write(html);
        printWin.document.close();
        printWin.focus();
```

If i am using `printWin.close();` it sudden close that window without download file. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest an alternative solution without using hidden iframes and opening / closing tabs. In HTML5 you can use an attribute on a link called `download`. A sample code using purely JS would be:

```
// Select your download button
var btn = document.getElementById('DOWNLOAD-BTN-ID');
    // The url to your PDF,
    // probably the result of the code you have now running in your iframe.
    btn.href = url;
    // Name your file and add the .pdf extension.
    btn.download = 'FILENAME.pdf';
```

When the user clicks on that button, the pdf will be downloaded without leaving the page.

If you need to trigger the download at runtime, you can add an extra line that acts as if the user clicked on the download button, the result is that the PDF is downloaded when you run your function.

```
btn.click();
```

Comment: file is too big so it will taking some time to generate, there is not already generated file will download. when url triggeres, file generation will process. so user have to wait while file generating. mean while user have to wait. thats why i am trying to open it in new tab. so no need to wait for user to generate pdf.

Comment: Fair enough :) disregard my first answer. Let me add another one to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the way you have it, `printWin.close();` will not wait for the code in your iframe to finish. What you need to do is self close the new window when it is done creating the PDF. At the end of the code in your new window, you can add: `window.close();`

Comment: you mean i need to add script tag in my new window?

Comment: That is it! The code that generates your pdf will run, and only then, the window should close, otherwise the new window does not have a chance of running your code.